# ng2-bs3 modal dynamic sizing?

Tags: css, angular, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have been using an `ng2-bs3` modal for my admin login form, but when the validation message comes, it is overflowing the modal body. How to fix it so that, when the message comes, its size also increases relative to the modal size?

Example:

[image: login page]

Comment: add your code to help you further

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle or codepen example so we can help troubleshoot the issue?  Bootstrap 3 modals don't have a fixed height, so there's probably something else that's causing this issue.